# Combine several events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text field and a button. Either when the button is clicked or <kbd>enter</kbd> is hit, a function should be executed.

My approach works is intended. However, is it possible to combine those 2 functions (`click` and `keypress`), so that I only have 1?

```
$("button").click(function() {
  getInput();
});

$("#name").keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    getInput();
  }
});

function getInput() {
  alert($("#name").val())
}
```

So I need to just append those events.

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ak871qfz/).

Comment: Not really - you've already made the actual work a separate function, so there's no duplicated code.  The issue is that the handler for click and keypress are very different, so you end up checking if you've got a keypress in order to check which key.  You slightly can improve with `$("button").click(getInput)`;.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen for multiple events using `.on('listOfEvents')`

Than you just need some additional rules to check when you need to run function.

```js
$("button, #name").on('click keypress', function(e) {
    if ($(e.currentTarget).attr('id') == 'submit' || e.which == 13) {
    getInput();
    }
});

function getInput() {
    alert($("#name").val())
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="name" />
<button id="submit">
  OK
</button>
```

Comment: I am asking this out of curiosity, $("button, #name).on('click keypress') will bind keypress to button ? and click to textbox ? don't you think events are added unnecessarily

Comment: @Kira Yes, but it's OP request

Answer (score 1):

```js
function getInput(){
  return $(".result").text($("input").val());
}

$("form").on("submit", (ev)=>{
  ev.preventDefault();
  // handle submission
  getInput();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <input type="text" />
  <button>ok</button>
</form>
<div class="result"></div>
```

you can wrap your input and button in a form and listen for a submit event on that form. Forms can be submitted by pressing enter in an input inside of them or clicking a button that is enclosed

HTML

```
<form action="">
  <input type="text" />
  <button>ok</button>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
$("form").on("submit", (ev)=>{
  ev.preventDefault();
  // handle submission
  getInput();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

@eltonkamami answer is one idea and my idea is to provide same class for both input field and button like this :

(But, this will trigger whenever input field is changed)

```js
$(".same").bind("click keypress", function() {
  getInput();
});

function getInput() {
  console.log($("#name").val())
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="name" class="same" />
<button id="submit" class="same">
  OK
</button>
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: This is an interesting idea, but it doesn't detect the enter-event.

Comment: Yes, every key triggers this function. But you never check explicitly for the enter key. Something like `if (e.which == 13)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("button,#name").on("click keypress",function(e) {
  //alert($(e.currentTarget).html());
  if (e.which == 13) {
    getInput();
  }else if(event.type == 'click'){
    getInput();
  }
});

function getInput() {
  alert($("#name").val())
}
```

Comment: can you explain what you did exactly

Answer (score 0):

We can differentiate a click and keypress by `e.key` or `e.type` parameters

Try this,

```js
var getInput = function(e) {    
  if((e.which & e.which==13) || !e.key) 
    //e.key is a parameter for keypress event and not for click
    alert($("#name").val())
}

$("button").click(getInput);

$("#name").keypress(getInput);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="name" class="same" />
<button id="submit" class="same">
 Click
</button>
```